# Snort not showing dropped/blocked packets

Tags: ids, denial-of-service, snort

This question is about SNORT-  I m basically trying to detect  **PING FLOOD attack.**
 I have included the 
         rule**(drop icmp any any -> any any (itype:8; threshold, track by_src, count 20, seconds; msg:"Ping flood attack detected"; sid:100121))** 
for that in the ddos.rule file of snort.

Attacking using the command **hping3 -1 --fast** .

The ping statistics in the attacking machine says: 100% packet loss. however Snort action stats shows the verdicts as:Block ->0.

Why is this happening?

Comment: where is your snort sensor(s) compared to where the ping is being blocked?

Comment: When you run  a packet capture where you have the snort box I assume you see these icmp packets?